# how to switch between mobile and web versions of the auth dialog

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk

When I pass my users through the app accept auth dialog they could either be mobile or the web but currently using the php sdk they all seem to be pointed to the web accept dialog.

Anyway I could specify the site I wish the users to go through in the sdk or how best would I handle this situation for facebook?

Comment: According to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/server-side/ Facebook does the hard work for you by rendering device specific versions automatically.

Comment: on my blackberry it just loads the normal dialog which is tiny. Do I have to specify something in the app settings?

Comment: I don't think you do, I'd submit that as a bug (depend on what you mean by 'normal' dialog).

Comment: normal being the desktop dialog you get in your standard browsers- i may regex out www for m if the user is on a mobile device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else with the problem- i used [this library](http://code.google.com/p/php-mobile-detect/wiki/Mobile_Detect) to detect if the user is on a mobile device and then str_replace'd www. with m.

```
//generate our url for the view
$data['loginUrl']   =   $this->facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope' => 'read_stream,publish_stream,status_update',
                                                                           "redirect_uri" => base_url()."social/pre_network_select2/new_facebook_save/")

                                                                   );
//check if the user is on a mobile device
if($this->Mobile_Detect->isMobile()){

    $data['loginUrl'] = str_replace('www.','m.',$data['loginUrl']);

}
```